# How To Show Latitude Longitude location in alertDialog Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i have a activity

```
package com.commonsware.android.constants;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ConstantsBrowser extends ListActivity {
  private LocationManager lm;
  private LocationListener locListener;
  private TextView latTxt, lonTxt;

  Intent intent = null;
  private static final int ADD_ID = Menu.FIRST+1;
  private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST+3;
  private static final int UPDATE_ID = Menu.FIRST+4;
  public static final int SHOW_SUB_ACTIVITY_VIEW=3;
  private DatabaseHelper db=null;
  private Cursor constantsCursor=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.banner);

    latTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeTxt);
    lonTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitudeTxt);


    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locListener = new MyLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 10,locListener);

    db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    constantsCursor=db
                      .getReadableDatabase()
                      .rawQuery("SELECT _ID, title, value "+
                                "FROM constants ORDER BY _ID",
                                null);

    ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                          R.layout.row, constantsCursor,
                          new String[] {
                                        DatabaseHelper.ID,
                                        DatabaseHelper.TITLE,
                                        DatabaseHelper.VALUE},
                          new int[] {R.id.id, R.id.alamat, R.id.value});

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    constantsCursor.close();
    db.close();
  }

  private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (loc != null) {
                latTxt.setText(String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
                lonTxt.setText(String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, ADD_ID, Menu.NONE, "Data Baru")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.add)
        .setAlphabeticShortcut('a');

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case ADD_ID:
        add();
        return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE_ID, Menu.NONE, "Delete");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, UPDATE_ID, Menu.NONE, "Update")
        .setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case DELETE_ID:
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info=
          (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

        delete(info.id);
        return(true);

      case UPDATE_ID:
          intent = new Intent(ConstantsBrowser.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SHOW_SUB_ACTIVITY_VIEW);
          return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
  }


    private void add() {
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View addView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_edit, null);

    final DialogWrapper wrapper=new DialogWrapper(addView);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle(R.string.add_title)
      .setView(addView)
      .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                              int whichButton) {
          processAdd(wrapper);
        }
      })
      .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                              int whichButton) {
          // ignore, just dismiss
        }
      })
      .show();
  }

  private void delete(final long rowId) {
    if (rowId>0) {
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.delete_title)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
            processDelete(rowId);
          }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
          // ignore, just dismiss
          }
        })
        .show();
    }
  }

  private void processAdd(DialogWrapper wrapper) {
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues(2);

    values.put(DatabaseHelper.TITLE, wrapper.getTitle());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.VALUE, wrapper.getValue());

    db.getWritableDatabase().insert("constants", DatabaseHelper.TITLE, values);
    constantsCursor.requery();
  }

  private void processDelete(long rowId) {
    String[] args={String.valueOf(rowId)};

    db.getWritableDatabase().delete("constants", "_ID=?", args);
    constantsCursor.requery();
  }

  class DialogWrapper {
    EditText titleField=null;
    EditText valueField=null;
    View base=null;

    DialogWrapper(View base) {
      this.base=base;
      valueField=(EditText)base.findViewById(R.id.value);
    }

    String getTitle() {
      return(getTitleField().getText().toString());
    }

    String getValue() {
      return(getValueField().getText().toString());
    }

    private EditText getTitleField() {
      if (titleField==null) {
        titleField=(EditText)base.findViewById(R.id.title);
      }

      return(titleField);
    }

    private EditText getValueField() {
      if (valueField==null) {
        valueField=(EditText)base.findViewById(R.id.value);
      }

      return(valueField);
    }
  }
}
```

i succes to show latitude longitude in my main activity

but the dialog not show the latitude and longitude

my dialog is in the same activity

here is the interface

[image]

how to show latitude longitude in the dialog?

**EDIT**

i add this but force close

```
private void add() {
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View addView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_edit, null);

    final DialogWrapper wrapper=new DialogWrapper(addView);
    TextView tvsellAll = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitudeTxtt);
    TextView tvsell10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitudeTxtt);
    tvsellAll.setText(latTxt.toString());
    tvsell10.setText(lonTxt.toString());
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle(R.string.add_title)
      .setView(addView)
      .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                              int whichButton) {
          processAdd(wrapper);
        }
      })
      .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                              int whichButton) {
          // ignore, just dismiss
        }
      })
      .show();
  }
```

nullpointer in line `tvLat.setText(latTxt.toString());`

please help me

BR

Alex

**SOLVED**

i forget to add `addView` in `findViewById`. Thanks All

Comment: use dialog instance for accessing TextView's if u have still added TextViews in dialogBox

Comment: yes i still add TextView in dialogBox. can you give me some code? @ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 0):

I think your using a different view for alert box. So u have to get the text view from that view and set the longitude and latitude.